# NMinimize with elimination returns strange results

Tags: performance-tuning, mathematical-optimization, fitting, dataset

I have a  parameter vectors `pars`, `par1`, and a matrix `data1` together with a vector result `values[[All,1]]` and vector weight `values[[All,2]]`.

```
pars = ToExpression["a" <> ToString[#]] & /@ Range[20]

data1 = {{0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 2., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 3.,
0., 0., 
  0., 0., 0.}, {1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 2., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
  0., 5., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 2., 
  0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 7., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0.}, {0., 0., 4., 0., 0., 
  0., 0., 0., 2., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 7., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 
  0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 2., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 9., 1., 0., 0., 
  0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 2., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
  9., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 2., 0., 
  0., 0., 0., 0., 9., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
  0., 0., 2., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 17., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 
  0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 6., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
  0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 10., 
  1., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 
  0., 0., 0., 10., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 
  0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 14., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 
  0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 14., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
  0.}, {2., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 18., 
  0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 
  0., 0., 0., 18., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 
  0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 9., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 
  0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 15., 0., 1., 0., 0., 
  0.}, {0., 2., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 4., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 4., 
  0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 4., 0., 0., 
  0., 0., 0., 6., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
  0., 4., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 8., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 
  0., 9., 0., 0., 0., 4., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 12., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
  0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 4., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 16., 
  0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 4., 0., 0., 
  0., 0., 0., 18., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0.}, {0., 5., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
  0., 4., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 20., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 
  0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 4., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 24., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
  0.}} 

values ={{428., 1.}, {456.6, 1.}, {497., 1.}, {471.8, 0.8}, {531.9, 
      0.9}, {514.3, 0.95}, {483.7, 1.}, {6441., 1.}, {436., 1.}, {493.2, 
      1.}, {550.2, 1.}, {550., 1.1}, {523.1, 1.}, {607.5, 1.}, {584.4, 
      1.}, {433.3, 1.}, {532., 1.}, {613.1, 1.}, {632., 1.}, {651., 
      1.}, {685., 0.9}, {712., 0.95}, {726., 1.}, {736., 1.}, {767., 1.}}
```

I want to find parameters for the function: `a21 + a22 * Total[weight*Abs[(Total[pars * data1] - values[1])/values[1]]] +  a23 * Total[weight * Abs[((Total[pars * data1] - value[1])/value[1])]^a24]` with the following code:

```
pars1 = Append[Append[Append[Append[pars, a21], a22], a23], a24]

sum2 = 0;

For[i = 1, i < Length[values[[All, 2]]], i++, 
  sum2 = sum2 + 
    values[[i, 2]]*
     Abs[((a21 + a22*Total[pars*data1[[i, All]]] + 
           a23*Total[pars*data1[[i, All]]]^a24) - values[[i, 1]])/
       values[[i, 1]]]];

sum2;

NMinimize[sum2, pars1]
```

The found parameters seem to be wrong because `a10` and `a20` should be zero for this case.

I also want to eliminate (to drop) the case `i` and re-find the parameters when the difference between the function value with the found parameters and `values[i,1]` is too large, e.g., the relative difference is more than 10%. I don't know how to solve these problems.

Could you please advice me how to solve these problems. Thank you in advance for your support.

Comment: Parameters a1, a10, a14, a20 do not appear in sum2. Therefore they could have any value.  But to get a reasonable result you should not specify these variables in NMinimize. E.g.:  `NMinimize[sum2, Complement[pars1, {a10 , a20, a4, a14}]]` gives a result of: 2.945

Comment: @DanielHuber :  Thank  you for your comments. NMinimize for this  case gives the strange  results. Lets see: NMinimize[sum2, pars1]; NMinimize[sum2, Complement[pars1, {a10, a20}]]; NMinimize[sum2, Complement[pars1, {a10, a20, a4, a14}]] gives strange results. Furthermore, let see simplest case:  sum1 = 0;
For[i = 1, i < Length[values[[All, 1]]], i++, 
  sum1 = sum1 + 
    values[[i, 2]]*
     Abs[(Total[pars*data1[[i, All]]] - values[[i, 1]])/
       values[[i, 1]]]];
sum1;
NMinimize[sum1, pars] --> best results. What is the problems of  the NMinimize?

Comment: You must understand that for a non-convex problems without constrains there is no method that will find the global minimum with 100% accuracy.  You would have to sample at infinite many points.  It is always possible that a local minimum is found. The lowest minimum I can find is 1.17524 using the method "RandomSearch".